# ExtendedToolkit DatePicker Calendar FontSize

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-extended-toolkit

I am using the ExtendedToolkit for WPF C#. Specifically I am using the DateTimePicker, I have tried changing the font size for this element however it does not change the size of the attached calendar that you use to select the date;

[image]

Is there a way to change it's FontSize in the ExtendedToolkit so it appears larger?

Answer (score 3):

I have the requirement for Calendar control to display larger numbers and since DateTimePicker uses Calendar, the same solution applies here.

Calendar has `CalendarDayButtonStyle` property for customizing date fields. The only property to change is `CalendarDayButton.FontSize`:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <xctk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Calendar">
            <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton" 
                            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </xctk:DateTimePicker.Resources>
</xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

[image: calendar]

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a copy of template and style for `Calendar` and `CalendarItem` through Blend tool and override the default FontSize. The copy I have generated through Blend is :

```
<Style x:Key="CalendarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE4EAF0" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF0F4" Offset="0.16"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFD" Offset="0.16"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{DynamicResource CalendarItemStyle1}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CalendarItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,0,3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static CalendarItem.DayTitleTemplateResourceKey}">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="#FF333333" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="9.5" FontFamily="Verdana" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,6,0,6" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Root">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledColor" Color="#A5FFFFFF"/>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="1">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.Resources>
                                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="PreviousButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF73A9D8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="path"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <Rectangle Fill="#11E5EBF1" Opacity="1" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Path x:Name="path" Data="M288.75,232.25 L288.75,240.625 L283,236.625 z" Fill="#FF333333" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="10" Margin="14,-6,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="6"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="NextButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF73A9D8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="path"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="path"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <Rectangle Fill="#11E5EBF1" Opacity="1" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Path x:Name="path" Data="M282.875,231.875 L282.875,240.375 L288.625,236 z" Fill="#FF333333" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="10" Margin="0,-6,14,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="6"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF73A9D8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="buttonContent"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="buttonContent"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="buttonContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextElement.Foreground="#FF333333" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1,4,1,9" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Grid.Resources>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource PreviousButtonTemplate}" Width="28"/>
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_HeaderButton" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" Focusable="False" FontSize="10.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <Button x:Name="PART_NextButton" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="20" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource NextButtonTemplate}" Width="28"/>
                                        <Grid x:Name="PART_MonthView" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,-1,6,6" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid x:Name="PART_YearView" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,-3,7,6" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_DisabledVisual" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledColor}" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource DisabledColor}" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_DisabledVisual" Value="Visible"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisplayMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Calendar}}}" Value="Year">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_MonthView" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_YearView" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DisplayMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Calendar}}}" Value="Decade">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_MonthView" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_YearView" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

**Step 1 :**

Create a Style for a Calender

```
<Style x:Key="styleCalendar" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
            <!-- Wrapping in ViewBox will enlarge calendar of that size.-->
            <Viewbox Height="400"
                     Width="400">
                <CalendarItem x:Name="CalendarItem"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**Step 2 :**

Apply Style for your DatePicker.

```
<DatePicker CalendarStyle="{StaticResource styleCalendar}" 
Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="datePicker1" Width="120" />
```